# typescript declare type as a property of class

Tags: typescript, typing

```
class Icons{
    static home = "<svg...";
    static back = "ico/back.png";
}

class Menu{
    addItem(icon: ????){....}
}
```

What type would you declare in the icon parm of Menu.addItem to force it to be a member of class Icons?

So far

```
addItem(icon:[keyof typeof Icons]);
menu.addItem("home", someFn);
```

approximates and validates using the property names as strings but, is it possible declare it a type that would let me express the direct reference to the property of Icons

```
menu.addItem(Icons.home, someFn);
```

I suspect I am missing something quite elemental here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string enum:

```js
enum Icons {
    home = "<svg...",
    back = "ico/back.png"
}

function addItem(icon: Icons) {
    console.log(icon);
}

addItem(Icons.home);
```